# Whats the fastest xml validator for linux platform

Tags: xml, linux, validation

I work with xml files that have up to 10000 events in them each with about 30 lines. So each xml file could have 300000 lines. I want to incorporate xml validation into my pre processing process and was wondering what are the fastest xml validation options available on a linux platform. To start off with I analysed xmllint as a validator and found that the 10000 event files took up to 1 sec (with the first taking a whopping 5 secs):

```
bash$ for file in `ls xml*xml`; do echo "checking $file of event length `grep '<event ' $file | wc -l`"; time xmllint --noout $file; result=`echo $?`; if [[ "$result" == "0" ]]; then echo "$file : valid"; else echo "$file : invalid returned $result"; fi; done

checking xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T06:31:49_PFS_1_2.xml of event length 810

real    0m0.251s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.020s
xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T06:31:49_PFS_1_2.xml : valid
checking xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T06:42:36_PFS_1_1.xml of event length 10001

real    0m5.363s
user    0m0.564s
sys     0m0.292s
xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T06:42:36_PFS_1_1.xml : valid
checking xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T07:27:36_PFS_1_2.xml of event length 10000

real    0m1.303s
user    0m0.732s
sys     0m0.232s
xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T07:27:36_PFS_1_2.xml : valid
checking xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T07:54:42_PFW_1_1.xml of event length 990

real    0m0.098s
user    0m0.072s
sys     0m0.024s
xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T07:54:42_PFW_1_1.xml : valid
checking xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T08:10:32_PFS_1_2.xml of event length 10000

real    0m0.971s
user    0m0.712s
sys     0m0.240s
xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T08:10:32_PFS_1_2.xml : valid
checking xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T08:56:57_PFS_1_2.xml of event length 10000

real    0m1.252s
user    0m0.724s
sys     0m0.184s
xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T08:56:57_PFS_1_2.xml : valid
checking xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T09:26:10_PFS_1_2.xml of event length 10000

real    0m0.920s
user    0m0.644s
sys     0m0.260s
xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T09:26:10_PFS_1_2.xml : valid
```

Does anybody have faster xml validators that I could use to achieve this?

A

Comment: Are you actually looking to validate the XML (as in, check that it conforms to a DTD) or just checking that it's well-formed? From the command line it looks like you're doing the latter. If you're looking for something faster than libxml2, take a look at AsmXml (http://tibleiz.net/asm-xml/index.html) or RapidXml (http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Bonus tip: Bash `for ... in` takes file globs (so no need to run `ls` ): `for file in xml*xml` works just fine.

Comment: just looking for well formed really. Thanks for the tip on file globs and I'll look at asmxml and rapidxml. thx

Answer (score 1):

I believe RXP is the fastest validating XML parser or at least it has this reputation. I have used its python binding but never the plain C.

Its available from http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/rxp.html

Comment: It is only for windows/dos.

Comment: @AdamArold it is available for both Unix and Windows. The source is available under GPL and can be built on Unix. A Windows binary is also released - to quote the author "An MSDOS/Windows executable is here (not usually the latest version)".

Comment: Sorry it seems I missed something. Edit your answer so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @AdamArold not sure what needs editing on my answer. RXP can indeed work for Unix. The link is already included in my answer.

Comment: My vote is locked. I can't change it until you edit your answer. Capische?